How to Integrate GridDB with Laravel Using a Custom Database Driver?
I'm working on a Laravel project where I want to use GridDB as my database. Since Laravel doesn't have built-in support for GridDB, I'm trying to create a custom database driver to handle the connection, since there's a connector for PHP in their docs. Here's what I've done so far:

Created a custom database driver:

'connections' => [ // Other connections...
'griddb' => [
'driver' => 'griddb',
'host' => env('GRIDDB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('GRIDDB_PORT', 10001),
'cluster' => env('GRIDDB_CLUSTER', 'myCluster'),
'username' => env('GRIDDB_USERNAME', 'admin'),
'password' => env('GRIDDB_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
],
],


Created a service provider for it:

class GridDBServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function register()
{
$this->app['db']->extend('griddb', function ($config, $name) {
$config['name'] = $name;
return new GridDBConnection($config);
});
}
}


Added the Connection class:

class GridDBConnection extends Connection
{
protected $gridstore;



public function __construct(array $config)
{
$factory = StoreFactory::getInstance();
$this->gridstore = $factory->getStore([
'notificationMember' => $config['host'] . ':' . $config['port'],
'clusterName' => $config['cluster'],
'user' => $config['username'],
'password' => $config['password'],
]);



parent::__construct($this->gridstore);
}
}



Added the service provider:

'providers' => [
// providers ..
App\Providers\GridDBServiceProvider::class,
]


So when I try to run migrations I get

unsupported driver [griddb].

Does anyone know what is happening, why is the connector not connecting?

Are you sure you installed GridDB correctly on your operating system?
Make sure you have installed the GridDB driver for PHP and activated the plugin.
Just check installation steps on:https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/#install-with-apt-get
